# Is keeping a lock on a record for a long period of time common practice with modern database systems?

Tags: sql-server, locking, firedac

**Question : Is keeping a lock on a record for a long period of time common practice with modern database systems ?**

My understanding is locking records in a database (optimistic or pessimistic) is usually for very short period of time during a transaction.

The software I'm working with right now keeps locks on records for long periods of time :

- A lock is kept on the record of the logged in user (in the ACTIVE_USERS' table) for the whole time the user is logged in the software.
- Let say USER A is working on a file.  The record corresponding to the file is locked until USER A saves the file or exit the file. So if a colleague, USER B tries to work on the same file, a popup shows up saying 'You can't work on this file because USER A is working on it right now'.

The company I'm working for to implement compatibility with Microsoft SQL Server wants the changes to be minimal : so I need to implement such a locking mechanism.  I've hacked something that is working on a minimal test project but I'm not sure it is up to the industry and MSSQL's standards ...

Comment: I hope users never go to lunch :-).

Comment: What do you mean with *locks on records*? Is this a RDBMS lock actually or some kind of *self-administered* lock flag?

Comment: @Shnugo: it's not merely a flag : an actual RDBMS lock is applied. our code (using Advantage Database Server's functions) applies a lock on a record in the database.  Our code is in Delphi and we use modules from Advantage database Server to apply locks.  Such functionnality doesn't exist when working with a MSSQL database (tru Delphi's FireDAC modules)

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: This project is going to run on SQL-Server and the impact should be as small as possible? Even if a concept is rather weird, the new solution should be as close as possible? You might read about *instead of TRIGGERs*. This would allow you to implement such a logic yourself...

Comment: @Shnugo: I'm wondering what you have in mind for the 'Instead of trigger' to be doing

Comment: It's not common to lock record for the logon time. I would personally avoid locking even in case when the record starts to being edited (by some frontend editor). Instead I would create a separated table tracking "editors" and let the record to be locked only by transaction.

Comment: No this is highly unusual and a definitive way to bring the pain in ongoing maintenance. I would avoid it like I avoid the plague. See Gordon Linoff answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Using the database locking mechanism for this application-level locking seems unusual.  Database locks could be on the row, page, or table level, and they also affect indexes, so there could be unexpected side effects.  Obviously, a proliferation of locks also makes deadlocks much more likely.

Normally, application locks would be handled on the record level.  Using flags (of some sort) in the record, the application would ensure that only one row would have access to the file.

I would say, it might work.  But I would never design a system that way and I'd be wary of unexpected consequences.

Comment: Agreed! Database locks are there to deal with ACID compliance(for starters) not application level logic. A in memory data structure maybe?